# Null Pointer Exception from Java UDP

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

Here's my main method:

```
public void broadcastName(final String name, final InetAddress broadcastIP) {
    // Broadcasts the name of the device at a regular interval
    System.out.println("Broadcasting started!");
    Thread broadcastThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String request = "ADD:"+name;
                byte[] message = request.getBytes();
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                socket.setBroadcast(true);
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, broadcastIP, BROADCAST_PORT);
                while(BROADCAST) {
                    System.out.println("socket: "+socket);
                    socket.send(packet);
                    System.out.println("Broadcast packet sent: " + packet.getAddress().toString());
                    Thread.sleep(BROADCAST_INTERVAL);
                }
                System.out.println("Broadcaster ending!");
                socket.disconnect();
                socket.close();
                return;
            }
            catch(SocketException e) {
                System.out.println("SocketException in broadcast: " + e);
                System.out.println("Broadcaster ending!");
                return;
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IOException in broadcast: " + e);
                System.out.println("Broadcaster ending!");
                return;
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException in broadcast: " + e);
                System.out.println("Broadcaster ending!");
                return;
            }
        }
    });
    broadcastThread.start();
}
```

I consistently get this error the moment I get to socket.send(packet) right after the while(BROADCAST) line.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException: null address || null buffer
at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Unknown Source)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(Unknown Source)
at application.ContactManager$2.run(ContactManager.java:103)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I checked to ensure that both socket and packet are not null! What else could be the culprit here?

What is the meaning behind this error message?

**EDIT**

I am running this code from Eclipse on a Windows, laptop machine.
The way I retrieve the IP address and setup broadcastIP is like this:

```
private static InetAddress getBroadcastIp() {
    // Function to return the broadcast address, based on the IP address of the device
    try {
        String addressString = InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString();
        InetAddress broadcastAddress = InetAddress.getByName(addressString);
        return broadcastAddress;
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("UnknownHostException in getBroadcastIP: " + e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try commenting out your while loop but leave the contents of the loop I commented to see if you can even get through cleanly once. If not I'd start checking to verify that your IP and message are still valid after each send.

Comment: How are you building your broadcastIP?

Comment: @klog Right, I cannot get through the while loop even once. It throws the exception at the second line in the while loop. I will start looking into the message & broadcastIP

Comment: @Evin1_ I setup my broadcastip by getting the localhost and calling the toString method on it. I read somewhere on SO that getLocalHost may not work in all cases but should be find for the most part.

Comment: @Evin1_ You're intuition is brilliant! I was incorrectly trying to obtain the ip address. Instead of toString(), I needed to call InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(); to get the String object for my ip! Thank you for your suggestion! I am no longer getting the Exception and the while loop is properly executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the solution here, as @WayWay mentioned in the comments:

---

The current code is not behaving properly when trying to get the IP address, since the result of the `.toString()` can't be resolved, so instead of:

```
String addressString = InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString();
InetAddress broadcastAddress = InetAddress.getByName(addressString);
```

You should try to retrieve it with:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
```

That way you will get the proper `InetAddress` that your broadcasting needs.